# .NET - how do I make a filled CustomLineCap that doesn't unfill the line overlap?

Tags: .net, graphics

I am trying to draw a line in .NET that uses a solid arrow CustomLineCap, but the portion of the cap that intersects with the line is not filled.  I tried setting all of the Y-coordinates in the cap's path to non-negative numbers, but the CustomLineCap constructor threw a "Not Implemented" exception; apparently, the cap must intersect the negative Y-axis (i.e. the line itself) somewhere other than at the line's endpoint.

Here is the code I am using for the CustomLineCap:

```
    GraphicsPath ArrowCapPath = new GraphicsPath();
    ArrowCapPath.AddLine(new Point(0, 4), new Point(2, -1)); 
    ArrowCapPath.AddLine(new Point(2, -1), new Point(-2, -1));
    ArrowCapPath.AddLine(new Point(-2, -1), new Point(0, 4));
    CustomLineCap ArrowCap = new CustomLineCap(ArrowCapPath, null);
```

The "arrow" is a triangle with height 5 and width 4.  The line itself goes 1 into the triangle, and this is the portion that is not filled.

How do I get the entire cap to be filled?

Comment: The MSDN example at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.customlinecap(v=vs.110).aspx doesn't have any negative coords.

Comment: It may be related to the "direction" your points take around the arrow (clockwise / counter-clockwise). MSDN says that end caps always use the `Winding` fill mode to determine what is inside the shape.  You might try reversing the direction of the points.  Since it looks like the entire line is drawn as one merged path, any intersections will cause fill issues.  I doubt you will be able to use negative coords and have it behave sanely. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.fillmode(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Bradley - the example is for a hook-shaped open line, and not something that needs to be filled.
However, your suggestion to change the direction of the line worked; when I changed the signs of the X-values, the arrow is now filled properly.

Comment: I'll create a nicely worded answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the "Direction" your points take around the shape.  CustomLineCaps [always](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a7yh63h9(v=vs.110).aspx) use the Winding [FillMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.fillmode(v=vs.110).aspx), which isn't the default fill mode used for`GraphicPath`, which finds the inside of a shape based on clockwise and counter-clockwise angles between points.  The point order you are using will cause the GDI to think your cap is "inside-out" and not fill it in.

Reversing your points should fix the problem, making the "outside" the "inside" and allowing the fill algorithm to work the way you expect.